# Azure ML Internal Error

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

When I try to test my Azure ML model, I get the following error: “Error code: InternalError, Http status code: 500”, so it appears something is failing inside of the machine learning service. How do I get around this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run into this error before, and unfortunately, the only workaround I found was to create a new ML workspace backed by a storage account that you know is online. Then copy your experiment over to the new workspace, and things should work. It can be a bit cumbersome, but it should get rid of your error message. With the service being relatively new, things sometimes get corrupted as updates are being made, so I recommend checking the box labeled "disable updates" within your experiment.  Hope that helps!

Comment: For future users, I had this problem and it was because the # of columns in my data set after feature construction was too large - it was on the order of a few thousand columns.